# Keyboard shortcut for moving (not copying) files in Finder

Tags: finder, shortcut

I copy and paste files in Finder all the time, but when I do I end up with both the original file and the copied file.

Is there another shortcut besides CMD-V that will just move the file instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly, all you have to do is add the <kbd>option</kbd> key to your keyboard shortcut. So, within Finder, use:

1. <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the file
2. <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to **move** the file

Comment: Doesn’t dragging without command move the file too?

Comment: @11684 Actually, you're right. I've edited that out so that my answer focuses specifically on the question scenario (i.e. about files that have been copied). Thanks! :)

Comment: @11684 That is the behavior only if you're moving the file to another location on the same filesystem.  If the destination is a different filesystem the default operation is a copy (which you can override with the appropriate modifier).